# Why is this? How number variable gets 5 different values? How does it remember?

Tags: c

The code below requests 5 numbers and prints asterisks of given numbers. How does number variable remember 5 numbers? Doesn't the next number entered destruct value inside variable? I don't understand. Can you explain it to me?

Below code gives output:

```
Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 30: 28 5 13 24 7
    ****************************
    *****
    *************
    ************************
    *******


#include <stdio.h> 
int main( void ){    
    int i;      
    int j;      /* inner counter */   
    int number; /* current number */   
    printf( "Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 30: " );  /* loop 5 times */   
    for ( i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
        scanf( "%d", &number );      /* print asterisks corresponding to current input */      
            for ( j = 1; j <= number; j++ )      
            printf( "*" );

    printf( "\n" );
    } /* end for */   
return 0; 
 }
```

Comment: Bad question. It doesn't remember the numbers. It prints it out and then it's replaced by the next number entered.

Comment: When I first look at the code, I expect to see something like first the number is entered than it is printed, the next number is entered, its asterisks are printed isn't it? But when I compiled and ran it, it takes whole 5 numbers bulk, then it prints them all bulk????

Comment: @user1939432 It wasn't clear from your original question that you wanted to understand why *entering all five numbers separated by a space on the console* had the same effect as *entering the five numbers one-at-a-time by hitting return*.

Comment: Maybe thing that is problematic for me is Stdin thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to your question is:
The text will be dumped in the stdin when you press "enter". scanf(..) reads from the stdin and thus parses all the 5 integers for you (one by one). scanf will only block if stdin is empty. So the values are not store in the number variable but on stdin.

Comment: Thanks they are located in stdin then and called back by the loop and assigned to variable 5 times. I see

Answer (score 2):

It's because the printing happens in between each read.  Notice that `scanf` is inside the loop `for ( i = 1; i <= 5; i++ )` and so is the second loop `for ( j = 1; i <= number; j++ )`.

So what actually happens is:
1.  Read input into `number`
2.  Print asterisks
3.  Goto 1.

The code does not actually remember all 5 numbers - it only remembers the current number.

Comment: Then why is the output bulk ?

Comment: Try inputting only one number at the prompt and not 5 and see what happens.

Comment: Note that `scanf` reads until whitespace, not until the end of the line.  But when you click enter, the whole input is put into `stdin` and then later read by the program, as brano said above.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah it is very IQ type Question. Look at the Line 
 printf( "Enter 5 numbers between 1 and 30: " );

than their is a "for loop" to take values. This loop cover the rest of the code.
So when first "number" take value the 2nd "for loop" starts it works & after finishing return to the 1st "for loop" to take the 2nd Input from keyboard & so on...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't hold all 5 numbers.  Your code sets the value of number and then prints the relevant number of * characters.  It then receives a new value on successive iterations of your first for loop.  The variable is re-used, rather than being set to multiple values at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you enter a number in the program, 'int number' gets set to that number.

The old value has been replaced and is no longer accessible.

Read about it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_(computer_science)

May I suggest not starting programming with C and maybe starting with something like Python.